# connection pooling and load on site

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

If my connection pooling is set to 10 and 100 users hit a page utilizing connection to DB at almost the same time.
Than in this case will the 90 users have to wait for connections to get free?
OR
More connections would be created for 90 users but they shall not be returned to pool?

FYI: I know connection pooling and related concepts. The query is in relation to page which generate large reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will have to wait for a connection to be returned to the pool if the maximum of 10 has reached, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

> The connection pooler satisfies
>   requests for connections by
>   reallocating connections as they are
>   released back into the pool. If the
>   maximum pool size has been reached and
>   no usable connection is available, the
>   request is queued. The pooler then
>   tries to reclaim any connections until
>   the time-out is reached (the default
>   is 15 seconds). If the pooler cannot
>   satisfy the request before the
>   connection times out, an exception is
>   thrown.